# Hexagonal grid/tiles tutorials

Tags: tiles, hexagonal-grid

Are there any platform or language agnostic (preferably step by step) tutorials regarding creating hexagonal grid based maps/games? I'm mainly interested in grid/tiles basics and not advanced game engine stuff. So far I have found these:

- [Hexagonal grid for games and other projects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/hexagonal_part1.aspx)
- [Hexagonal grid math](http://www.gdreflections.com/2011/02/hexagonal-grid-math.html)

Comment: For some more hex maths, see: [How do I rotate a structure of hexagonal tiles on a hexagonal grid?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/how-do-i-rotate-a-structure-of-hexagonal-tiles-on-a-hexagonal-grid) (I think we could need a `hexagons` tag ...)

Comment: Yeah I wanted to add hexagonal tag but I don't have enough reputation here :/

Comment: Why are you unsatisfied with those two tutorials? One on gdreflections.com is great and quite simple too. Any specific "weak points" you have in mind?

Comment: @Vigil: those which I posted are pretty good, I'm just asking if there are some other recommended resources regarding this topic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have been working on a hex tile game and found these tutorials useful:

- [Coordinates in Hexagon-Based Tile Maps](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/sweet-snippets/coordinates-in-hexagon-based-tile-maps-r1800)
- [Isometric 'n Hexogonal Maps Part I](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/isometric-and-tile-based-games/298/isometric-n-hexagonal-maps-part-i-r747)
- [Isometric 'n Hexogonal Maps Part II](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/isometric-and-tile-based-games/298/isometric-r748)
- [Drawing a Hex Grid in Illustrator](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3603631) (for designing maps)

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 45):

This guide didn't exist when the question was asked, but here's my guide to hex grid math:

- [Hexagonal Grids](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)

Comment: It is a good one. Your tutorial is awesome for anyone starting to use hexes.