# Magnitude of a vector in Generalized Balanced Ternary?

Tags: grid, hexagonal-grid, roguelikes

[Generalized Balanced Ternary](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.games.roguelike.development/L4j_ETTFc2s/p7IZ82EWdZQJ) is a fairly obscure but very elegant method of indexing a hex grid, using only a single integer coordinate. Operations like addition and multiplication on these coordinates have intuitive effects: translation and rotation respectively.

The only difficulty with GBT is calculating the magnitude of a vector given its coordinate, or alternatively, of decomposing it into a series of one-unit steps. Is there a standard method of doing this?

Comment: This looks similar to [a system I've seen asked about previously, called "Spiral Honeycomb Mosaic"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/71785/39518). You may be able to adapt the method shown there to convert into a more conventional representation to generate the magnitude. It looks at a cursory view like only the sequence of terms in the lookup tables would need to change.

Comment: @DMGregory Oh excellent! Yeah, Spiral Honeycomb Mosaic is a type of GBT with a different order of the digits. Makes the addition table weirder imo but works just the same.